# Logging in to Instagram using Python requests module

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to log in into Instagram with python `requests` module. As I checked this site with Firefox Developer Tools I saw that whenever I click the login button a request is sent to `instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/` as you can see below:

[image: requests]

So I wrote this piece of code:

```
import json, requests
ses = requests.session()
url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/"
payload = { 'username':'****' , 'password':'****' }
req = ses.post(base,data= json.dumps(payload))
```

But the response object (`req`) contains a HTML page with this error:

"This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action"

What should I do?

Comment: Try in your post call, send `params` rather than `data`

Comment: Why don't you use the Instagram Python library?

Comment: @AvihooMamka please explain more

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's something about learning web concepts not just passing it :D